# Ajax request from Fluxxor not dispatching success action

Tags: ajax, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I am trying to use jquery.ajax from a Flux action using Fluxxor. I am working off of the Async example at http://fluxxor.com/guides/async-data.html.

The call is successful (I'm getting a response), but I can't figure out why it's not dispatching LOAD_BUZZ_SUCCESS.

I am replacing this block of code:

```
 var BuzzwordClient = {
      load: function(success, failure) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          success(_.range(10).map(Faker.Company.catchPhrase));
        }, 1000);
      }
    //...
    };
```

with

```
var BuzzwordClient = {
  load: function(success, failure) {
      jquery.ajax({
          url: "test.json",
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);

          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
              console.log("error");
          }.bind(this)
      });
  }
//...
};
```

The call is here from the actions var:

```
BuzzwordClient.load(function(words) {
      this.dispatch(constants.LOAD_BUZZ_SUCCESS, {words: words});
    }.bind(this), function(error) {
      this.dispatch(constants.LOAD_BUZZ_FAIL, {error: error});
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

Do I need to wrap the ajax call with something else? What is the client's load function supposed to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```javascript
BuzzwordClient.load(function(words) {
  this.dispatch(constants.LOAD_BUZZ_SUCCESS, {words: words});
}.bind(this), function(error) {
  this.dispatch(constants.LOAD_BUZZ_FAIL, {error: error});
}.bind(this));
```

The two functions passed to `load` are available in the parameters `success` and `failure` in the `load` method:

```javascript
var BuzzwordClient = {
  load: function(success, failure) {
```

But these functions are never called. Notice how the original example calls the passed `success` function, passing in the words:

```javascript
success(_.range(10).map(Faker.Company.catchPhrase));
```

You need to do the same in your Ajax callbacks:

```javascript
var BuzzwordClient = {
  load: function(success, failure) {
      jquery.ajax({
          url: "test.json",
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            success(data); // or something similar
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            failure(err); // or something similar
          }
      });
  }
//...
};
```

Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/6p98L2h8/

> What is the client's load function supposed to return?

In general, asynchronous functions don't return anything. The value you care about is not available until some later time (which is what makes it asynchronous), so you need to use the callbacks for execution flow.

You could also use something like promises to abstract away part of this, but in JavaScript you'll still fall back to callbacks at some point.

Comment: Thanks! I now am able to trigger the success callback but the payload is the success object and not the response. How can I extract the response form this object? Doing payload.responseJSON does not seem to work (gives me an undefined). Thanks!

Comment: @sutee The payload of an action is the second parameter to `this.dispatch`, so in this case it's the object `{words: words}`. If you want to include extra data, you need to put it there yourself, probably modifying the `success` callback to `BuzzwordClient.load` to accept the necessary data.

Comment: Perhaps my question is now out of the scope of this question, but I am trying to figure out how to extract my response JSON from the payload. In my case, words is an object returned by my ajax response, and I can't figure out how to get extract the JSON returned by the "server". When I dispatch to LOAD_BUZZ_SUCCESS and try to do payload.responseJSON inside of onAddBuzzSuccess, I can see the payload but the responseJSON is undefined. It might be a timing issue. I think my question is more about jquery but it would be nice to see a fluxxor example of making a call with a json response. Thanks!

Comment: @sutee Yes, you're probably right. Take a look at [this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/6p98L2h8/) and [contact me](http://brandontilley.com/contact.html) if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thanks for the example! It helped me get everything working. My problem was that I was wrappinghe `success` callback function over the whole ajax call. I think the example would be helpful to others starting out with Fluxxor as well!